# Backstretch images not appearing

Tags: jquery, jquery-backstretch

Hi having a problem with no images loading for the past 5 days of trying with backstretch.  Checked all my file paths, have proper library plugins, checking order of markup, checked order of scripts.  Any ideas?  please help!  Thanks so much -- and apologize for being a newbie.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="new_website/new_site_css/stylesheet2.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="CSS" charset="utf-8" />

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">


 </head>    

 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript"    
 <script    type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"src="new_website/jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
 <script>
 $.backstretch([
"new_website/images/2.png",
"new_website/images/3.png",
"new_website/images/4.png"    
], {duration: 4000, fade: 750});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't have any css declared, FYI.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think to initialize a slideshow you need to declare an element.

```
$(".foo").backstretch([
        $(".foo").backstretch([
           "path/to/image.jpg",
           "path/to/image2.jpg",
           "path/to/image3.jpg"    
      ], {duration: 4000});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that full path of image is added because `"new_website"` directory may not be at the same level as this page.
2. Make sure that all images have read permission. If read permission isn't there, though images are exist, they won't appear into browser.

   ```
   $(".foo").backstretch([

      "absolute path/to/image.jpg",
      "absolute path/to/image2.jpg",
      "absolute path/to/image3.jpg"

    ], {duration: 4000});
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to select an HTML element that you want to change the background of. For example, if you want to change the `body` of the document, you'd use:

```
$("body").backstretch([
  "new_website/images/2.png",
  "new_website/images/3.png",
  "new_website/images/4.png"
], {duration: 4000, fade: 750});
```

I threw a [quick example together](http://jsfiddle.net/86w2vomm/) so that you can see it in action. Let me know if you have any questions!